# Generating a saved page with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, save

I wondered if it were possible to generate a .html file using Javascript and then to save it to a webserver?

if the variables for example were:

```
var firstname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
var secondname = document.getElementById("second_name").value;
```

and the form looked like:

```
<form id="submit_form">
<input type="text" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" id="second_name" />
<button id="submit" onclick="generate()">
</form>
```

to generate a .html file to be posted onto a server looking like:

> firstname: "firstname"
>
> secondname: "secondname"

Is there a way of making this possible? (the example vars are not going to be used in the finished site). I know there is POST with php, but I wondered about using Javascript/JQ only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to "save" content to a server, you NEED a server-side component. Be it PHP, Java, or whatever language you are comfortable with - you need a server component. HTML and JavaScript live in the browser only (for security reasons).

If you don't care about saving it to the server, but rather you just want to show the HTML page to the user, you could I guess overwrite the entire page in jQuery to make it look like what you want.